# 1970's or 80's time travel movie/TV episode with aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, time-travel

I remember only a brief scene from this episode/movie. The scene was in black and white. The main character was a soldier who had gone back in time, actually meeting himself as a kid. This soldier was hiding in bushes, or the kid showed him a hiding place under the front porch of a house and was spying on a group of aliens.

The aliens (Martians?) had 3 all black eyes and were dressed like Men in Black with suits, fedoras, and trench coats. The aliens may have been searching for the soldier. As he was observing them they were greeting someone, or making a deal. The aliens were also driving late 50's or early 60's black sedans.

The soldier was Caucasian, blond? Curly hair, had a beard? His uniform was a mix of old and new, modern (green? solid color)M65 field jacket and WW2 German leather suspenders. He had a Kennedy half dollar that he gave to his younger self, which is how he realized the kid was himself as a boy.

I am thinking that this may have been an outer limits episode.

Comment: It all sounds more Twilight Zone than Outer Limits - but no one episode that I can put my finger on. In "Walking Distance" the central character goes back and meets his 10yo self, but recognises him by his pocket knife rather than a coin. OTOH, a Kennedy half-dollar figures in "Profile In Silver", where the owner gets into trouble because living Americans can't be portrayed on coins and the (pre-Dallas) authorities suspect him of wrongdoing. Could you be conflating two or moew episodes?

Comment: You said Outer Limits, but the originals were all b&w. Was it just that scene in b&w, or the entire episode?

Comment: In the War of the Worlds episode "A Time to Reap" January 29, 1990, the alien invaders open a time portal to immunize the original invaders in the 1953 movie War of the Worlds against Earthly germs, and one of the protagonists has to go back to stop them from changing history.  I don't remember enough details to say how closely the plot fits your memory, but this might be the episode you remember, even though that series was usually in color.

Comment: @ Mike Stone @ The guest  The original Twilight Zone (1959-1964) and Outer limits (1963-1965) were in b&w, the revived Twilight Zone (1985-1989)  & (2002-2003) and Outer Limits (1995-2002) were in color.  Note that color movies and episodes can have b&w scenes due to use of stock footage or for storytelling reasons.

Answer (score 5):

This was the War of the Worlds episode "A Time to Reap".

@M.A. Golding, You were correct! I YouTubed "Time to Reap", and I finally got to see the whole episode. I didn't even know there was a War of the Worlds series. I only ever saw the one episode and apparently only pieces of that one.

@the guest, that one episode was filmed in both color and b&w, which was used for the 1950's sequences. I only remember seeing the b&w part of the episode.

@Mike Stone, my memory was flawed, the character I remembered used the Kennedy half dollar to pay for a newspaper, and he gave his younger self a large glass marble. I gotta look up those Twilight Zone episodes now!

Comment: You can (and should) accept your self-answer in about 26 hours (48 hours after asking) by clikcing on the checkmark by the voting buttons (clicking early will just tell you how much time is left). Congrats on finding your answer! Is there anything more you can add to the answer to confirm it fits, now that you know what it is that you are looking for?